# Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: node.js

I am using express node.js with mysql to build the api's and want to connect these api's to the front end but i have face an error, due to this my application didn't run properly plzzzz tell me whats the problem in my code.

And my error is :
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USEcoffee_shop' at line 1

```
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('USE' + dbconfig.database);

module.exports = (passport)=>{
    passport.serializeUser((user,done)=>{
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id,done)=>{
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ", [id],
            (err,rows)=>{
            done(err,rows[0])
        });
    });

passport.use(
    'local-signup',
    new LocalStrategy({
        api_keyField : 'api_key',
        nameField : 'name',
        phoneField : 'phone',
        emailField : 'email',
        photoField : 'photo',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback:true
    },
    (req,email,password,done)=>{
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",[email],
            (err,rows)=>{
                if(err)
                    return done(err);
                if(rows.lenght){
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage','That is Already Taken'));
                }else{
                    var newUserMysql = {
                        api_key : api_key,
                        name : name,
                        phone : phone,
                        email : email,
                        photo : photo,
                        password : bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)
                    };

                    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users (api_key,name,phone,email,photo,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    connection.query(insertQuery, [newUserMysql.api_key, newUserMysql.name, newUserMysql.phone, newUserMysql.email, newUserMysql.photo, newUserMysql.password],
                        (err,rows)=>{
                            newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                            return done(null, newUserMysql);
                        });

                }

            });
    })

    );

passport.use(
    'local-login',
    new LocalStrategy({
        emailField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback:true
    },
    (req,email,password,done)=>{
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email],
            (err,rows)=>{
                if(err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!rows.lenght){
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No User Found'));
                }
                if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage','Wrong password'));

                    return done(null, rows[0]);
            });
    })

    );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is pretty self explanatory buddy.

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the ***right syntax to use near 'USEcoffee_shop'*** at line 1

This code: `connection.query('USE' + dbconfig.database);` translates to `connection.query('USEcoffee_shop');`

But SQL doesn't recognize `USEcoffee_shop` as a valid syntax. There has to be a blank space between `USE` and the Db name.

Hence modify your code to:

```
connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database); //observe the space after USE
```

This should work.

Comment: my error has been removed but on my console this "GET / - - ms - -" type of message has occur whats the reason.

Comment: I might need to see more of your code @UmarMasood, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39748608/10232790) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, with mysql you can also specify the database as part of the connection setup:
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                   host     : 'localhost',
                   user     : 'me',
                   password : 'secret',
                   database : 'coffee_shop'
                 });
```

So you would not have to perform the 'USE' query in a separate call.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong code: `connection.query('USE' + dbconfig.database);`

Right code: `connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);`

You missed a space after the keyword USE